# How should I comment partial Python functions?

Tags: python, function, comments, partial

say I have the following code:

```
def func(x, y = 1, z = 2):
    """ A comment about this function """
    return x + y + z

another_func = partial(func, z = 4)
```

What would be the correct or Pythonic way of documenting the another_func function?

Comment: [the most correct way is demonstrated in the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: user368186, did my answer work for you? If so can you select it as correct?

Comment: Sorry, in my delayed response. Busy day. That is great thankyou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See partial() description on http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Like this:

```
another_func.__doc__ = "My documentation"
```